# Spring Injects Non Beans into RestController Method

Tags: java, spring

While creating a small demo for Spring 6, I made a mistake, and injected a bean into a REST controller method instead of into it's constructor.

The Bean was not configured correctly, for example a singleton was not a singleton.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Spring6DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Spring6DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
@Service
@Scope("singleton")
class Pojo {
    String greet() { return "hi "; }
}
@RestController
class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/greet/{name}")
    String greet(Pojo pojo, @PathVariable String name) {
        System.out.println(pojo);
        return pojo.greet()+name;
    }
}
```

Calling the REST end point twice printed out two different Pojo objects.

> curl http://localhost:8080/greet/Gonen
>
> com.example.Spring6Demo.Pojo@1e46c103
>
> curl http://localhost:8080/greet/Gonen
>
> com.example.Spring6Demo.Pojo@f715efd

Further investigation showed that the Pojo objects get injected even when they are not configured spring beans at all.

```
//@Service  // no change in behavior - spring still injects this non bean
//@Scope("singleton")
class Pojo {
    String greet() { return "hi "; }
}
```

I was quite surprised despite working with Spring for many years.
Is this a known issue, or documented wrong use of the Spring API?

Comment: I currently have no time for an extended answer, but it is expected behaviour.
More infos are available at the documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-constructor-injection

Comment: Using @Scope("singleton") unnecessary. Not related to your question though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Pojo` class is a parameter to a controller method. Spring will map the web request to your parameter (i.e. `Pojo`).
Injected instances are *not* beans, but are constructed and bound to your request parameters for each request. They are not registered in the application context.

For instance, the following code would return "Gonen" when requesting `http://localhost/greet?name=Gonen`:

```
class Pojo {
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(final String name) { this.name = name; }
}

@RestController
class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/greet")
    String greet(Pojo pojo) {
        return pojo.getName();
    }
}
```

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods

Comment: Thanks. I think a more appropriate reference would be
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-initbinder-model-design

Comment: Or possibly https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-multipart-forms